# SQL Giving a 1 for the first duplicate and rest be 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for a way to only count 1 duplicate account but list them all. sort of like this for excel but for SQL `=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)>1,IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1,1,0),"")`

Any thoughts on how to do this

Data is like

```
Acct#   Instance    Duplicate Count Code
8         A10             1         R3
8         A10             0         R4
8         A10             0         R15
10        B30             1         C1
10        B30             0         C7
10        B40             1         C10
```

Comment: how about

`select count(yourcolumn), yourcolumn from yourtable group by yourcolumn`

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: what does the Duplicate Count field represent? Also what fields should we be considering as unique in order to find duplicate rows?

Comment: Can you also show the desired output?

Comment: I could be misinterpreting your question - but a `CASE` statement might be what you need here - e.g. `CASE WHEN [clause] THEN [outcome] ELSE [default] END` - Links: [SQL Server](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/case.php) - [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)

Comment: I am using MYSQL sorry. ACCT# and Instance are the Duplicate field, Duplicate count is what I am looking for and Code is an additional field I need to show which is going to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured a way to get the answer I was looking for. I expanded my query to include amount and the date and below is what I came up with.

```
    case when max(amount) = amount and ROWNUMBER() OVER (Partition by ACCT# concat INSTANCE concat DATE
        ORDER BY ACCT# concat INSTANCE concat DATE DESC) = 1 then 1
when amount in (0) then 0 else 0 end as "# of Instances"
```

Comment: that isn't valid SQL, please include a more complete answer